# Why am I not getting any errors but database has no record inserted?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm trying to add a record to a database in a control in C#:

```
public partial class ctrl_Register : UserControl
{
    public ctrl_Register()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_reg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool ok = false;
        int col = 1;
        if (tBox_username.Text != "")
        {
            if (tBox_password.Text != "")
            {
                if (cBox_colour.Text != "")
                {
                    ok = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ok)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.data2cString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Table](Id,username,password,colour,bestTime) VALUES ('"+tBox_username.Text+"','"+tBox_password.Text+"','"+cBox_colour.Text+"')";

                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("added");
                    }
                    catch (SqlException s)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(s.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no insert");
        }
    }
}
```

The message box "added" shows up, so the code definitely gets to that point.  However when I go check my database there is no new record.

This was my create table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] 
(
    [Id]       INT          IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [password] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [colour]   VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT ('Orange') NULL,
    [bestTime] INT          DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

It's definitely the correct connection string in the settings file. But when I go to the `data2.mdf` file in the database explorer and go to 'Show Data' for the table, only NULL is present.

Comment: Just a side-note, use parameters instead of concatenating SQL string with textbox values to avoid security issues.

Comment: Put a break point on the ExecuteNonQuery statement. Run the code and it will pause there. Capture the cmd commandText property into the clipboard. Open SSMS and try to run it there. Observe the results. This debugging technique will save you hours of time.

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement has 5 column names, but you only supply 3 column values. I'm stunned that this doesn't give you an SQL exception.

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: That was a copy-paste accident. I original had 5 values but then changed the code and forgot to update the first bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't **show** the connection string - but since you're saying to "go to the `Data2.mdf` file in the server explorer, I *assume* you're probably using an `AttachDbFileName=` approach.

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Data2`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Data2;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

And also: do **NOT** ever concatenate together your SQL command like this - this is just **asking** for a script kiddie to explore SQL injection to attack your site. Use **parametrized queries** - always, no exception.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Yes it was the wrong mdf file.  To anyone reading this, |DataDirectory| is not the mdf file in the project folder.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you are going to write SQL code. Check for errors. You are supplying three values for five columns, so that is likely an error.

Second, use parameterized queries. Don't put user input directly into the query string. This is dangerous and well as an impediment to the SQL optimizer.

Third, don't name a table `Table`. That is a reserved word. Use a non-reserved word that better describes the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Change your command text and use parameters like:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Table](username,password,colour) VALUES(@username, @password, @colour)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tBox_username.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  tBox_password.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@colour", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  tBox_colour.Text;
```